# Admob Mediation Questions

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm using Admob and i'd like to setup Mediation with Admob Mediation. Reading the google support Documentation, and Admob documentation i get confused due to some information is not clear or detailed.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Which is my mediation id? Reading from net, some tell mediation id is addUnitId in new Admob version. But im not sure.
2. Using Admob Mediation, it's necessary to add all SDKs from the different networks i want to use for mediation through admob mediation?
3. When adding a new Ad Network through Monetize > Select App > Edit Mediation > + New Ad Network, different ad networks require different forms of ID, such as App ID, Site alias, or APID... Were can i get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mediation id is your AdUnitId. It will look like ca-app-pub-someNumber/someOtherNumber
2. Yes.The library for each other ad network needs to be in your app.
3. This info comes from your account on the other ad network.

Comment: Can you please also clear if I need to make a separate ad-request for each mediation partner or AdMob handles it itself.

Comment: @WaqasYounis you only make a single AdRequest, AdMob handles the calls to the other networks.

Comment: @William but I am using AdMob as a mediation partner to Facebook Audience Network, not vice versa.